# Multiplicação e soma de inputs dinâmicos

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, sum

Obs: Desenvolvido com Laravel 5.7.
Obs 2: Essa é a view de "Novo Pedido".

O form receberá dinamicamente os produtos conforme seus itens cadastrados previamente. Até aí ok!

O usuário marcará o produto e informará a quantidade pretendida. O problema é o seguinte:
**Multipicar o valor unitário pela quantidade e somar os resultados!**

```
<div class="form-check">
  @php
  $p = count($produtos);
  $i = 0;
  @endphp
  @foreach ($produtos as $produto)
  @php
  $i++;
  @endphp
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-8 produto">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="produto_id[{{ $i }}]" value="{{ $produto->id }}" name="produto_id[{{ $i }}]" >
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1" style="margin-right: 10px">{{ $produto->nome }} - R$ {{ $produto->valor }}</label>
        <div class="valor">
        <input type="hidden" name="val_un[{{ $i }}]" value="{{ $produto->valor }}" id="val_un[{{ $i }}]">
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="col fields">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="quantidade[{{ $i }}]" name="quantidade[{{ $i }}]" onblur="sum()" placeholder="Quantidade" >  
    </div>  
  </div>
  <hr>
  @endforeach
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sum()
      {
        let total = 0;
        let valor = 0;
        let valor_un = 0;

        $('.fields input').each(function() {
            valor =  $('.fields input').val();
            valor_un =  $('.valor input').val();
            total_un = valor*valor_un;

            total = ????????????????????????????????????
        });
          $('#total').val(total);
      }
  </script>


</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="total">Valor Total</label>
      <input type="total" class="form-control" id="total" name="total" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="">
    </div>        
  </div>
```

Comment: Qual o formato dos valores em `value="{{ $produto->valor }}"`? Seria `10,00` (vírgula nos centavos), ou `10.00` (ponto nos centavos)?

Comment: Boa tarde @Sam, o valor vem já com ponto. Ex: 12.10

Comment: Então vou ter que alterar a resposta.. só um instante

Comment: Então @Sam, o valor retornado em total é NaN.. ainda não descobri o problema!! kk

Comment: Já alterei a resposta.

Comment: Caro @Sam, vou enviar novamente o código pra ver o que está acontecendo!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87045/discussion-between-sam-and-denis-vanoni).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Considerando que os valores em `value="{{ $produto->valor }}"` tem o
>   formato separando as casas decimais com ponto (ex., `70.02` ou `50.00`).

Como você está fazendo um laço nos inputs, em vez de `valor =  $('.fields input').val();`, seria `valor =  $(this).val();`, onde o `$(this)` faz referência a cada elemento percorrido pelo laço.

Para pegar o valor do produto, você pode usar o seletor:

```
$('[name="val_un['+i+']"]').val()
```

O `i` concatenado no `name` é cada iteração do laço, que começa com `0`:

```
                                 ↓
$('.fields input').each(function(i) {...
```

Para ir somando os valores, você faz:

```
total += total_un;
```

No valor total fiz um tratamento para ficar no formato com vírgula:

```js
function sum(){
   let total = 0;
   let valor = 0;
   let valor_un = 0;
   $('.fields input').each(function(i) {
      valor =  $(this).val();
      // pega o valor correspondente
      valor_un =  $('[name="val_un['+i+']"]').val();
      total_un = valor*valor_un;
   
      total += total_un;
   });
   
   // aqui eu substituo o ponto por vírgula para ficar no formato brasileiro
   // convertendo o número em string com .toFixed(2)
   // para poder fazer o replace
   total = total.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
   
   $('#total').val(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-8 produto">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="produto_id[0]" value="1" name="1" >
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1" style="margin-right: 10px">prod1 - R$ 50,13</label>
        <div class="valor">
        <input type="hidden" name="val_un[0]" value="50.13" id="val_un[0]">
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="col fields">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="quantidade[0]" name="quantidade[0]" onblur="sum()" placeholder="Quantidade" >  
    </div>  
  </div>
  <hr>
 <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-8 produto">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="produto_id[1]" value="2" name="2" >
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1" style="margin-right: 10px">prod2 - R$ 70,02</label>
        <div class="valor">
        <input type="hidden" name="val_un[1]" value="70.02" id="val_un[1]">
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="col fields">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="quantidade[1]" name="quantidade[1]" onblur="sum()" placeholder="Quantidade" >  
    </div>  
  </div>
  <hr>
total: <input id="total">
```